# create-react-app leverage HTTP caching

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, caching, heroku, create-react-app

I recently used `create-react-app` to make and deploy a website. I ran the website speed test at tools.pingdom.com and it looks mostly good. However, I'm getting an F for leveraging browser caching. More specifically, it says the following resources:

http://www.onlineomnichord.com/static/css/main.3d9308b8.css
http://www.onlineomnichord.com/static/js/main.7a110dad.js

have a short freshness lifetime.

I'm using heroku to host my website, so I read over some of their suggestions. At the end of [this article on HTTP caching](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers) they say that caching should be implemented within the web framework.

Is there a way to specify caching headers somewhere in my react project? I also read over the [create-react-app user guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md), and they say you can use a `.htaccess` file for Apache HTTP server. Is there something similar to that I should be leveraging?

Comment: So did you find the solution ?

Comment: Have u found the solution?